# How to insert auto incremented SORT_ORDER in single query

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update

For Multiple insert(update if already exists) I use the following query and is working perfectly.

```
INSERT INTO table (id,Col1,Col2)
VALUES (1,1,1),(2,2,3),(3,9,3),(4,10,12)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col1=VALUES(Col1), Col2=VALUES(Col2);
```

Now I need to enter `SORT_ORDER` along with the values, but it should be a auto incremented. What should be the technique to do it in single query?

Comment: why can't you use the auto-incremented id column for sort_order?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what I believe your question is: You want the sort order to be the order in which the rows are inserted or modified.

I think the easiest way to do this is by using a [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).